# Toast isn't working in listener

Tags: android, smack, toast

I want to open a Toast, but it doesn"t seem to work in a listener (of Smack), like this example:

```
private ChatManagerListener chatManagerListener = new ChatManagerListener() {

    public void chatCreated(Chat newChat, boolean createdLocally) {
        if(!createdLocally) {

            Toast.makeText(mCtx, "CHAT CREATED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // do some stuff

        }
    }
};
```

If I use the Toast-code somewhere else in the class, it works, as long as it isn't a listener.

Comment: remove condition... and check

Comment: once try by replacing mCtx to getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
   @Override  
   public void run() {  
      Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "import finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
   }  
});
```

Comment: but how in the hell did you know that this code is running in another thread ?!
am i missing something here?

Comment: if you are looking on real answer, ok here its, from his callback it seems he is using an chat library that have callbacks on another thread, because its not designed to run on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're assigning the appropriate Context. Your mCtx should be the context of the parent class.   Try assigning it like this:  ParentClassName.this

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it goes inside the if condition?
If so, then I think you are not getting the context there.